# Javascript: Mapping to create a subset array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

Not to experimented un Javascript. I've Looked at many examples on this site and can't quite get one that works for me... Or should I say can't make it work.

I have an array that when I run `console.log(Object.keys(MyArray)[0]);` returns `0`.

When I run `console.log(Object.values(MyArray)[0]);` returns:

```
ARM1_ALARM: 1 
ARM1_APM_CH1_Mode: 11 
ARM1_APM_CH1_Setpoint: 110 
ARM1_APM_CH1_Temp: 111 
ARM1_Air1: 1 
ARM1_Air2: 0 
ARM1_Air3: 1 
ARM1_Air4: 1 
ARM1_CycleNumber: 1001 
ARM1_Fans1: 0 
ARM1_Fans2: 0 
ARM2_APM_CH1_Mode: 21 
ARM2_APM_CH1_Setpoint: 210 
ARM2_APM_CH1_Temp: 209 
ARM2_Air1: 1 
ARM2_Air2: 0 
ARM2_Air3: 0 
ARM2_Air4: 1 
ARM2_CycleNumber: 2001 
ARM2_Fans1: 1 
ARM2_Fans2: 0 
ARM3_APM_CH1_Mode: 21 
ARM3_APM_CH1_Setpoint: 310 
ARM3_APM_CH1_Temp: 310 
ARM3_Air1: 0 
ARM3_Air2: 0 
ARM3_Air3: 1 
ARM3_Air4: 1 
ARM3_CycleNumber: 3001 
ARM3_Fans1: 0 
ARM3_Fans2: 1 
ARM4_APM_CH1_Mode: 21 
ARM4_APM_CH1_Setpoint: 410 
ARM4_APM_CH1_Temp: 411 
ARM4_Air1: 1 
ARM4_Air2: 0 
ARM4_Air3: 0 
ARM4_Air4: 0 
ARM4_CycleNumber: 4001 
ARM4_Fans1: 0 
ARM4_Fans2: 0
```

The array can have up to 18000 objects and 150 keys per object. I'm trying to map a subset array from the main array that includes "ARM1". Tried many combinations of map, filter, array.from, includes... Without any success.

The following line is not working, but that's something similar that I'm trying to make work. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var filteredarray = MyArray.map(function(d) {return Object.values(k => k.includes('ARM1'))});
```

As per @Jankapunkt's comment, here is the modified code that worked for me:

```
const filteredarray = [MyArray].map(entries => {
  // this is the array of Objects within the greater array
  return entries.map(obj => {
    // build a custom object that only contains ARM1 keys
    const arm1 = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (key.includes('ARM1')) {
        arm1[key] = obj[key] // copy property
      }
    })
    return arm1
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys` of Array will return the indices (0..n) because this is how Arrays store the values (associative array) in JavaScript.

When I get it right your Array contains Objects, and this is where `Object.keys` is valuable to get `ARM1` to be filtered.

Assuming your array is structured like so:

```
[
  [ { 'ARM1': 1, 'ARM3_FANS1': 0 }, ...],
  [ ... ],
  ...
]
```

You need to iterate twice here:

```js
const filteredarray = MyArray.map(entries => {
  // this is the array of Objects within the greater array
  return entries.map(obj => {
    // build a custom object that only contains ARM1 keys
    const arm1 = {}
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
      if (key.includes('ARM1') {
        arm1[key] = obj[key] // copy property
      }
    })
    return arm1
  })
});
```

result:

```
[
  [ { 'ARM1': 1 }, ...],
  [ ... ],
  ...
]
```

Use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or Array.flatMap in order to "flatten" your structure to your needs.

Comment: @ Jankapunkt, Wow! I'm almost into tears! Thanks for the added comments, it helps a lot to understand. It was missing a parentheses at the IF condition, I think. I get "entries.map is not a function" when running it, why?

Comment: @ Jankapunkt, it is now working. I've put MyArray in-between [ ]. It will permit me to continu my programming. Thanks for your time!!!